# Virtualbox-dkms giving errors every time I try use apt or ubuntu software

Tags: apt, virtualbox, software-center, dkms

ever since I upgraded to kernal 5.11.0-051100rc2-generic in order to fix an issue I was having, every time I try use the apt command or the ubuntu software app, I get errors.  In Ubuntu Software this looks like "Error while installing package: installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10".  Every time I tried using apt to install programs it would return an error and they often wouldn't function properly.  I tried purging virtualbox to try fix the error but I just get

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libgsoap-2.8.91 libllvm10 liblzf1
  libnvidia-common-450-server libvncserver1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.1.16 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.16
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.16 DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-051100rc2-generic
Building initial module for 5.11.0-051100rc2-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.11.0-051100rc2-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-051100rc2-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.16/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when I try use apt I'm still getting that error.  I then did

```
$dkms status
virtualbox, 6.1.16: added

$sudo dkms remove virtualbox/6.1.16 --all

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.16
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
```

And yet I still get

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Upon trying to use apt.  I would also like to fix this without deleting my VMs if that's at all possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: It is not supported for this kernel says the error message.

Comment: @user535733 I have installed the headers and I still seem to be getting the same error

Comment: @nobody How do I stop that from interfering with apt and installing other programs?  Is there any way to just delete it?

Comment: sudo dpkg  - P  Virtualbox-dkms

Comment: @nobody perfect, that works, thank you so much!